# How Save View Object in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

Guys we are can storage primitive type values in android with `SharedPreferences`, SQLite, etc... but I want save textView to layout. I created `textView` in Java class. How I can save created new TextView in Android?

Comment: Do you want to add that textview in layout?

Comment: @KarnShah i adding already but my app re-run my textviews removing on layout. I need saved into layout. and i create textView in java class.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the text contained in your `TextView` as a `String` to `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite`, etc.
Then all you have to do is to load this `String` back from `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite`, etc. and set it back to your `TextView`.
The same way you can store/restore `TextView`'s `textColor`, `textSize` and any other property you need.
You can not store any view but only it's content.

Comment: but i create TextView in java class not in xml? How i get back textview when my app is re-run.

Comment: Extract code which creates your TextView into separate method. Run this method any time you want anywhere you want.

Comment: You have to create that textview in every run of application.